# go and Fyne - Trying to create a single window that shows two different sets of information depending on button pressed

Tags: go, button, fyne

I have the following code which will not compile which shows two different sets of content depending on which button is pressed. The objective is to change content programatically based on buttons selected (in the same window).

The compile error is at line 19 and 27 saying content1 and content2 are undefined.

Problem Solution is more important than fixing compile error!

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
  "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
  "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
  "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
  myApp := app.New()
  myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("Hello")
  myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 600))
  label1 := widget.NewLabel("You are in content 1")
  button1 :=    widget.NewButton("Button 1", 
            func() {
                fmt.Println("tapped button1")
                myWindow.SetContent(content2)
                myWindow.Show()
            })
    
  label2 := widget.NewLabel("You are in content 2")
  button2 :=    widget.NewButton("Button 2", 
            func() {
                fmt.Println("tapped button2")
                myWindow.SetContent(content1)
                myWindow.Show()
            })  
  content1 := container.NewVBox(
    label1,
    button1,
    )       
  content2 := container.NewVBox(
    label2,
    button2,
)
  myWindow.SetContent(content1)
  myWindow.ShowAndRun() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t reference a variable before it is defined.
Try using `var content1 fyne.CanvasObject` (for example) before you reference it and changing `content1 :=` to `content1 =` so you update its value once you know it.

Comment: Andy, think you had a small meltdown, the hint was great but the code should read `var content1 fyne.CanvasObject` Works with adding variable declaration, allowing programatic changes to window content. I can now go back to the app and use the principle in earnest!

Comment: Thanks so much - I must have been half asleep